# Split the page using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I have been tasked with looking at into inserting content dynamically into a web page, by splitting the screen.

I really don't know what to begin as I would assume this is a form of jQuery accordion, but the entire page needs to split and content move accordingly.

```
*******************************
*                             *
* THIS IS                     *
* MY WEBPAGE                  *
*                             *
*******************************
```

This would becomes;

```
*******************************
*                             *
* THIS IS                     *
*                             *
* Inserted content here       *
*                             *
* MY WEBPAGE                  *
*                             *
*******************************
```

The content beneath the break would all move down with it. I see this as being very RESOURCE heavy if I have a lot of content to move below the split.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't really *offer* 'help or advice' (that'd be closed as ['not constructive' or 'not a real question'](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)), if you've made an attempt that isn't working, we can help with that.

Comment: I'm not sure about what do you want? Even less about what have you tried ;)

Comment: @Tom Sarduy: He just wants to know how to use jQuery to dynamically show content. Why is it so important to know what he tried? It's good to try, but sometimes we don't know where to start.

Comment: It's awkward i know and I really want to thank you guys for making sense of my vague answer.

I basically have a web page, but I have to insert a DIV of content at a certain point, when the user clicks on a specific link. Inserting this content results in everything BELOW the insertion point moving down the page, like it's being sandwiched in. i don't have enough REP to upload photos, so I had to make the vague drawings you see above :(

Comment: @PédeLeão: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Sorted it, it was the structure of my HTML page that was the problem. The DIV i wanted to slide open (like a drawer) had to be positioned elsewhere... I'll try and post my solution later :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you need a simple collapsible panel. There are a lot of them available. I like [Darren's](http://www.darreningram.net/pages/examples/jQuery/CollapsiblePanelPlugin.aspx).

An even more basic approach is to have an empty div which you can [load html](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString) into it using jQuery. When the div's html is loaded everything below it will automatically move down.

Comment: Therein lies the problem really. I had no idea what this method was called, if it even existed, sounds like Collapsible panels are the way forwards for this project, thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert a div withn your page with an id such as:

```
<div id="content">Hello World</div>
```

As the page loads, jQuery can hide the content with

```
$('#content').hide();
```

Doing it that way makes it possible to see the content if javascript isn't enabled.  Then you need a click function to show the content:

```
$("#show").click(function(){
    $("content").show();
});
```

I don't know exactly what you want to do, but you should consult the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/hide/.

Answer (score 0):

you can make attempt using a sngle div for your webpage and then positioning it as required.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but you could try [jQuery Simple Collapsible Panel Plugin](http://www.darreningram.net/jquery-collapsible-panel-plugin-2/).